# Word proximity in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-plugin

I have a requirement which I have to produce while searching in Elasticsearch. According to it, if we are searching for a string "My missing property file"
if the complete phrase is found in any field that doc is to be given a boost and 
if three words are found out of the 4 words then the doc be given a slighter lower boost.So basically we need give more relevance to keyword order match in the field.
so in the order

```
 "My missing property file" - most higher boost
 "missing property file" - second higher boost
 "missing property" - third higher boost.
```

Now when we have condition like we have fields containing "missing property file" and "My missing property" in this case the idf of each keyword should decide the relevance.

How can we achieve this in Elasticsearch ?
Any help or suggestion will be great

Answer (score 1):

A normal match query on the field should rank your hits in your desired order.

Comment: I might have not provided the clean picture, the order of keyword found should also affect the relevance. In summary we need to have proximity as well as the order in which the keywords are found.